# How can I split a list up into two groups? How can I print those groups?

Tags: python

I am making a randomizer to put in names and then print out those names in 2 even groups. I am trying to figure out how to split up the list into groups.

Comment: Show code please

Comment: not sure i follow the question, 

are you doing something like this?,

`namelist = ['joe', 'mary', 'bob', 'john', 'kevin', 'linda']


group1 = ['joe', 'mary', 'bob']
group2 = ['john', 'kevin', 'linda']
`

Answer (score 0):

If I get this right, you can use `numpy` and `random.sample` for this:

```
import numpy as np
import random

# here goes your list
your_list = np.array(["name1", "name2","name3", "name4","name5", "name6","name7", "name8"])
# get its length
n_names = len(your_list)
# generates a random list od indexes
groups = random.sample(range(n_names), n_names)
# split these indixes into two even groups
g1, g2 = groups[:n_names//2], groups[n_names//2:]
# put elements into two groups
group1, group2 = your_list[g1], your_list[g2]
# print them
print("Group1: ",group1)
print("Group2: ",group2)
```

If there's no problem lost the original ordenation of the names you could try this simples solution:

```
import random

# here goes your list
your_list = np.array(["name1", "name2","name3", "name4","name5", "name6","name7", "name8"])
# get its length
n_names = len(your_list)
# shuffle it
random.shuffle(your_list)
group1, group2 = your_list[:n_names//2], your_list[n_names//2:]
# print them
print("Group1: ",group1)
print("Group2: ",group2)
```

Comment: it saying "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Logan/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/test2.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'"

Comment: You have to install `numpy`, use `pip` for this, type `pip install numpy` in terminal

Comment: Sorry if i seem stupid. "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Logan/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/test2.py", line 6, in <module>
    groups = random.sample((n_names), n_names)
  File "C:\Users\Logan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\random.py", line 317, in sample
    raise TypeError("Population must be a sequence or set.  For dicts, use list(d).")
TypeError: Population must be a sequence or set.  For dicts, use list(d)."

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I forget the `range` in `random.sample`

Comment: where does that go?

Comment: In this line: `groups = random.sample(range(n_names), n_names)`

Comment: What would I do if I want the user to input names? I tried alot of stuff, but I cant figure it out, it always prints the same things for both groups.

Comment: Have you tried something similar to `names = input("User! Input some names now: ").split()`?

Comment: I just did, and it didnt work. is there something i need to import? how does the split work?

Comment: Those are python built-in functions,i.e., no need to import. The `split` splits a string  the character space as delimiter. I think it would be better you make another question with that other problem, because its getting out of scope here.